# mod_rewrite vs. redirect permanent

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

just a quick question! i am forcing my site to redirect from http to https. The way im doing it is in my httpd.conf file, i have in my virtual hosts a

```
redirect permanent / https://sitename
```

everything works fine and I got that setting from apache's wiki site! but my question is, which is faster the redirect permanent or using the mod_rewrite way?

Ive seen in some sites suggesting to use something like:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

but nobody explains if that way gets better performance than using redirect permanent or not? my site gets 1000+ visits per day and handles large files!

basically what is the difference between the two? I just want to make sure i am optimized for best performance ;)

PS. everything is done in my httpd.conf and NOT in .htaccess ;)

Comment: I'm not sure on the performance difference, but using httpd.conf instead of .htaccess is preferred since .htaccess files are processed for each request; the redirect is kept in memory and doesn't involve the extra overhead.

Comment: 1000 hits per day is around one hit every minute and a half (averaged out) - whichever you choose won't really make a difference. That said, I don't know which would be processed more quickly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> my site gets 1000+ visits per day

That's nothing; you really don't need to worry about the relative performance at that level of traffic.

Both methods are trivial performance-wise relative to whatever your site is actually doing for its pages.

Comment: Thank you, i guess i am going to keep it the way i have it for now!

Answer (score 0):

If you want finer control over your redirection then use mod_rewrite otherwise you can simply use mod_alias (or redirect permanent). eg: mod_alias doesn't give you control over query string checks etc. Please refer this documentation for more tricks/examples: http://my.opera.com/GreyWyvern/blog/2007/09/12/apache-mod-rewrite